itext7 System.BadImageFormatException on windows target
Im performing a simple paragraph add to document task in maui
doc.Add(paragraph1);
When i run this code in android, works fine, but when run it on windows, i got the following exception: (Anyone have any clues)
System.BadImageFormatException
Try github example called PDFSample and got the same error on windows
code snippet
//paragraph1
    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("MAUI PDF Sample")
   .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
   .SetFontSize(20);
    document. Add(paragraph1);

Try it first on android and then change target to windows and you'll receive the PE BadImage Exception.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"github example called PDFSample" - which exactly?

"Try it first on android and then change target to windows and you'll receive the PE BadImage Exception." - I don't have android targets installed. But I can run that code without issue with target Windows. Thus, I'd assume that in your setup VS for some reason cannot switch targets from Android to Windows properly. Some possible issues are explained on learn-microsoft.com.
